# TSQL - Assign value from query to variable if record exists in a single select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How I can improve below code to use 'select' only once?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [NUMBER] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [ID_RECORD] = @id_record
BEGIN
   DECLARE @tmp_variable
   SELECT @tmp_variable = [NUMBER] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [ID_RECORD] = @id_record

   SET @other_variable = @tmp_variable
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SET @other_variable = 0
END
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try This :

```
 DECLARE @tmp_variable INT
 SET @tmp_variable = ISNULL(( SELECT    [NUMBER]
                              FROM      [TABLE]
                              WHERE     [ID_RECORD] = @id_record
                             ), 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution:

```
DECLARE @tmp_variable int
SET @tmp_variable = null
SELECT @tmp_variable = [NUMBER] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [ID_RECORD] = @id_record

IF @tmp_variable is not null
BEGIN           
   SET @other_variable = @tmp_variable
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SET @other_variable = 0
END
```